# Adding an algorithm layout while using the graphsharp liabrary

Tags: c#, wpf, graph-sharp

I'm a student and working on a project of visualizing a graph.
Me and my partner decided to work with the graphsharp liabray, but we what a specific layout algorithm that shows the graph as an **adjacency list**. All the layout algorithms in the graphsharp liabrary aren't suitable.

- Is there an easy way to implement another algorithm layout in the
  graphsharp liabrary?

ps: It's kinda hard to work with graphsharp liabrary without any documentation.

thanks,
Alex